# ASP.NET membership can I get a directory to return 403?

Tags: asp.net, authorization

I have an existing app that I've been doing some authentication work on (fixing some long standing issues) and I'm happy enough with the login redirection under normal circumstances. For IIS7 I'm implementing an authorization HttpModule that I'm running on the whole IIS7 pipeline.

This works great but I'd like to get some subdirectories (actually virtual directories) of the main site to return 403 instead of a redirect. Is it possible to do this without implementing my own authentication module?

I've seen Sky Sanders work (code poet) but I'd like to avoid that if I can.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39062/Salient-Web-Security-AccessControlModule.aspx

It feels like something clever with a `<location="">` section should work but I can't figure out how to do that (or if it's even possible).

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a separate web.config for the sub directories and denying access to them (sub directory) using the deny verb in the sub directory's web.config. Something like deny="?" (? is the verb that identifies authenticated users). If you want a 403 for everybody try * instead of ?. I think this should work.

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work (well at least not for me), you just get redirected back to the login page.

Comment: Try setting <customerrors mode="off"> in the sub directory's web.config.

Comment: Nope adding (correcting the case to customErrors) that doesn't help either. Still get a redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm"/>
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm"/>
</customErrors>
```

(Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8x4ket8%28VS.80%29.aspx))

If this doesn't cut it, also add this in your Global.asax:

```
void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // if login failed then display user friendly error page.
    if (Response.StatusCode == 403)
    {
        Response.ClearContent();
        Server.Transfer("~/Common/Errors/AccessDenied.html");
    }
}
```

Hope this works.